# How to create AWS CloudWatch Subscription Filters for multiple Log Groups using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Good morning,

I have found those documents:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

I want to use CloudFormation to create Subscription, that will handle multiple Log Groups at once. Also, I want to create separate Subscription, that will handle *all* Log Groups.

Can I do it by single entry in CloudFormation yaml?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not. Have you tried developing such a template? If yes, what do you have so far and why it does not work as expected?

Comment: There is only one required argument connected to selecting the log group called logGroup name, and documentation points, that it is a string, not an array. I was thinking about some workaround, I really dont want to create FEW HUNDREDS of Subscribers (number of our labmdas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you mean now, and you are right [AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html) **does not support** creating multiple subscription at once.

If you really want to automate this and keep it within CloudFormation (CFN), you would have to develop CFN [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). In both cases you would have to write your own lambda function which could create your **subscriptions iteratively** in a loop, based on the input parameters, e.g. a list of log groups. The lambda would have to use AWS SDK for that with proper execution role.